# Google Calendar Scope for OAuth GoogleSignInOptions in Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am using Google Sign in to authenticate the user and add an event to user's Google Calendar. The event is added at the server side. GoogleSignInOptions objects is created as follows:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(**WHAT SCOPE**))
            .requestIdToken(Server_Client_ID)
            .requestServerAuthCode(Server_Client_ID)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

But when setting scope the scope for Calendar is not found in the list. There is EMAIL, PLUS_ME and a set of FITNESS_ACTIVITY scopes etc. But what should be the scope for Calendar?

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I figured it out. Strings can also be passed as parameter to the method for creating scope object. For managing calendar, is it 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar'. All the scopes can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestScopes(new Scope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar'))
        .requestIdToken(Server_Client_ID)
        .requestServerAuthCode(Server_Client_ID)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
```